# Access to Oracle DB 9.2 without Oracle Client using C #

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Is it always necessary to install an Oracle client to connect to a database via a self-written C # program.
Can I sew some kind of library into my program? As a result, to make the program independent of the oracle client installation?

Comment: Please edit the question and post the complete error trace.

Comment: Did you try setting the parameter "SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8"?  Add it to the Oracle 9i DB sqlnet.ora

Comment: "...it gives an error" - please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the error messages which you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this nuget package the "avoid a separate install" https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't thinks that's possible.

According to [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) you can connect to an Oracle 9.2 server with a client 11.2 or older.

The only driver which does not require an Oracle Client is the "Oracle Data Provider Managed Driver" (ODP.NET Managed Driver). However, it was introduced in Oracle 12.1, so the database must be 11.2 or newer.

Looks like you have to install an old Oracle Client. Perhaps one of the third party drivers will also work: [Progress](https://www.progress.com/connectors/oracle-database) or [DevArt](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/). However, they come with additional costs.

Comment: I redid the question, what I need, the previously described did not make sense to solve the problem.

Comment: ah, the version of the oracle db that works with (nuget package)....great catch. upvote.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Comment: thank you, I'll try